# is it possible to merge two fonts into one?

Tags: font-design

I have a font that supports only one language, when using the font with English I get the default English font for the language. I want to be able to add a specific English font to my language font. Is it possible ?

Comment: Just found this answer on superuser http://superuser.com/questions/490922/merging-two-font-into-one I wasn't looking for the right keywords I guess

Comment: if you found the solution, could you provide it below as an answer? For further reference?

Comment: Technically you can extend any typeface with characters using a wide variety of font editing tools. Aesthetically and legally, however, it's a whole other ballgame.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the merged font in Adobe InDesign, you can do it directly from there, and it's quite flexible, as well.

Go to Type -> Composite Fonts, in the Composite Fonts Editor you see you can have three different fonts merged into one, one for your original language (Base), one for the English characters (Latin) and then you can choose what font you'd like for the numbers. Select any of the three sets and, on the bottom of the dialog, you can customize each set's size, baseline, vertical scale, and horizontal scale.

But wait, that's not all, you can actually have as many fonts merged together as you'd like, click on the Custom button and have a field day customizing whichever character you'd like to any font installed on your system and create a custom set, which you can then add to the original three sets, and then customize all aspects of each set on its own.

Enjoy!